# Adding columns' name to each cell as a dictionary

Tags: python, pandas

Suppose I have the following dataframe:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({"call 1": ['debit card','bond',np.nan],
                  "call 2": ['debit card','mortgage','spending limit'],
                  "call 3":['payment limit','debit card',np.nan]})
```

I want to add the name of columns to each cell as a dictionary such that I get: **(EXPECTED OUTPUT)**

```
pd.DataFrame({"call 1": [{'call 1':'debit card'},{'call 1':'bond'}, {'call 1': np.nan}],
                  "call 2": [{'call 2':'debit card'},{'call 2':'mortgage'},{'call 2':'spending limit'}],
                  "call 3":[{'call 3':'payment limit'},{'call 3':'debit card'},{'call 3':np.nan}]})
```

The method I used is turning everything to string, namely,

```
pd.DataFrame({col:str(col)+', ' for col in df}, index=df.index) + df.astype(str)
```

which gives:

```
               call 1                  call 2                 call 3
0  call 1, debit card      call 2, debit card  call 3, payment limit
1        call 1, bond        call 2, mortgage     call 3, debit card
2         call 1, nan  call 2, spending limit            call 3, nan
```

So I wonder how can I do this task such that I get a dict in each cell?

Comment: What is your expected output?

Comment: it is on the question - it should be like: `pd.DataFrame({"call 1": [{'call 1':'debit card'},{'call 1':'bond'}, {'call 1': np.nan}],
                  "call 2": [{'call 2':'debit card'},{'call 2':'mortgage'},{'call 2':'spending limit'}],
                  "call 3":[{'call 3':'payment limit'},{'call 3':'debit card'},{'call 3':np.nan}]})`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
for col in df.columns:
    df[col] = df[col].apply(lambda x: {col: x})
```